# Flutter: The application's Info.plist does not contain CFBundleVersion

Tags: ios, flutter

Everything worked until I updated MacOS to v 10.15.7
I cannot assure this is the real problem, though.

The same code works perfectly emulated on Android, but I get the following errors when I run it on iPhone:

```
[   +2 ms] Unable to install /Users/***/project_dir/build/ios/iphonesimulator/Runner.app on 4E3679AE-08E6-4DBE-A940-20E4D34F2122. This is
sometimes caused
           by a malformed plist file:
           ProcessException: Process exited abnormally:
           An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=22):
           Failed to install the requested application
           The application's Info.plist does not contain CFBundleVersion.
           Ensure your bundle contains a CFBundleVersion.
             Command: /usr/bin/xcrun simctl install 4E3679AE-08E6-4DBE-A940-20E4D34F2122
/Users/***/project_dir/build/ios/iphonesimulator/Runner.app
[   +1 ms] Error launching application on iPhone 11 Pro.
[   +3 ms] "flutter run" took 41.403ms.
[  +10 ms] 
           #0      throwToolExit (package:flutter_tools/src/base/common.dart:14:3)
           #1      RunCommand.runCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart:607:7)
           <asynchronous suspension>
           #2      FlutterCommand.verifyThenRunCommand (package:flutter_tools/src/runner/flutter_command.dart:977:18)
           #3      _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
           #4      _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
           #5      _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
           #6      Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
           #7      Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
           #8      Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
           #9      _AsyncAwaitCompleter.complete (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:40:15)
           #10     _completeOnAsyncReturn (dart:async-patch/async_patch.dart:311:13)
           #11     RunCommand.usageValues (package:flutter_tools/src/commands/run.dart)
           #12     _rootRunUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1198:47)
           #13     _CustomZone.runUnary (dart:async/zone.dart:1100:19)
           #14     _FutureListener.handleValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:143:18)
           #15     Future._propagateToListeners.handleValueCallback (dart:async/future_impl.dart:696:45)
           #16     Future._propagateToListeners (dart:async/future_impl.dart:725:32)
           #17     Future._completeWithValue (dart:async/future_impl.dart:529:5)
           #18     Future._asyncCompleteWithValue.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/future_impl.dart:567:7)
           #19     _rootRun (dart:async/zone.dart:1190:13)
           #20     _CustomZone.run (dart:async/zone.dart:1093:19)
           #21     _CustomZone.runGuarded (dart:async/zone.dart:997:7)
           #22     _CustomZone.bindCallbackGuarded.<anonymous closure> (dart:async/zone.dart:1037:23)
           #23     _microtaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:41:21)
           #24     _startMicrotaskLoop (dart:async/schedule_microtask.dart:50:5)
           #25     _runPendingImmediateCallback (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:118:13)
           #26     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:169:5)
```

No problem with the flutter doctor:

```
╰─❯ flutter doctor
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.1, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H2, locale it-SE)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 12.0.1)
[✓] Android Studio (version 4.0)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.49.3)
[✓] Connected device (2 available)

• No issues found!
```

I've tried solving with solutions proposed in other threads but nothing worked.

My pubspec.yaml looks like this:

```
name: eat_eat_shop
description: Nom Nom.

version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.8.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  flutter_bloc: ^6.0.5
  equatable: ^1.2.5
  firebase_auth: ^0.18.0+1
  dartz: ^0.9.1
  freezed_annotation: ^0.12.0
  firebase_core: ^0.5.0
  google_sign_in: ^4.5.4
  cloud_firestore: ^0.14.0+2
  firebase_storage: ^4.0.0
  get_it: ^4.0.4
  injectable: ^1.0.4
  flushbar: ^1.10.4
  uuid: ^2.2.2
  auto_route: ^0.6.7
  image: ^2.1.17
  kt_dart: ^0.7.0+1
  json_annotation: ^3.1.0
  rxdart: ^0.24.1
  flutter_cache_manager_firebase: ^1.0.1
  file_picker: ^2.0.3
  flutter_hooks: ^0.14.0
  path_provider: ^1.6.18
  logger: ^0.9.3
  firebase_image: ^0.2.0

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
  mockito: ^4.1.0
  freezed: ^0.12.1
  lint: ^1.2.0
  injectable_generator: ^1.0.4
  auto_route_generator: ^0.6.8
  json_serializable: ^3.5.0

flutter:
  uses-material-design: true
  assets:
    - images/default_product_image.png
```

In my info.plist:

```
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NUMBER)</string>
```

As soon as I hard-code the CFBundleVersion happens the same thing with CFBundleShortVersionString:

```
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>$(FLUTTER_BUILD_NAME)</string>
```

I guess is some problem getting these variables from the env.

Thanks in advance,
Daniel

Comment: I am researching about both problems, but for the first one (CFBundleVersion) I execute this command: `agvtool new-version -all 2` in ios folder and the error go away.

Answer (score 6):

**The application's Info.plist does not contain CFBundleVersion**

The above error comes when we haven't declared `Version` filed, inside **Xcode**

[image]

**Note:** Version can be anything but to make sense we always start with `1.0.0` then increment the number as your release.

Comment: the above solution works, but I would expect the version from pubspec.yaml to be used to overwrite the info.plist values. This seems to work when running directly on emulator or device but not when building ipa?

Answer (score 1):

I had the right version for my main target but I was forgetting about my other targets, make sure they also have a version and build number[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and it occured because of an error in formatting info.plist file and I solved it by returning it to the default view.

Answer (score 0):

#### Steps

1. Open Visual Code
2. Delete the iOS directory
3. Click on at the bottom right to select a device
4. Instead of a device, select `Enable iOS for this project`
5. Run `flutterfire configure` to re-add any firebase dependencies
6. Re-run the app as usual on the iOS simulator

There's some sort of config which gets broken when updating parts of the project. Not sure how to fix it directly, but doing these steps is pretty easy for small projects.

You could also just do the steps and then do a git compare to only pick the changes which fixes the issue and revert everything else.